# Google oauth process: User seeing developer information dialog during log in

Tags: google-oauth

I have user that is using our Google integration to log into our online application.  When the user get's to the screen to "Choose An Account" during the sign in processes, and selects their account, instead of signing them in, and forwarding them back to the application to finish the log in process, they are shown a "developer information" dialog.

The dialog has "Developer Info" as a title, with my email (as the developer contact), and the text "Choosing an account will redirect you to (website address)."  The last thing is a "Got it" button, that when clicked acts as a "mailto" link to my email address.

This doesn't appear to be happening to all of our users, it seems to be just the one, or a handful, but I can't find anything online about this, and wanted to know what is happening, and how I can avoid it occurring.

Comment: This is a security dialog that Google presents to the user. You cannot block it. For the email address that is displayed, create an email address you want to be public.